# understanding the difference between two linked list implementations in c

Tags: c, pointers

For a month or two since i started learning data-structures , using `C`, i have been following a particular method of writing linked list. Which looks like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int exponent;
    int coeff;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node N;
N *st = NULL;

void insert(N *node, int c, int e){
    N *temp;
    node->exponent = e;
    node->coeff = c;

    if(st == NULL){
        node->next = st;
        st = node;
    } else {
        temp = st;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        node->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = node;
    }
    printf(" %p", st); //this is written on purpose, not that i write it everytime
}
```

and i call this from the main method,

```
N *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
insert(node, 1, 2);
```

The output of the printf for four such calls is
`00340D18 00340D18 00340D18 00340D18`

i.e the value of the start pointer remains constant, but if i make a small change in the code

```
typedef struct Node N;

void insert(N *node, N *st, int c, int e){
    N *temp;
    node->exponent = e;
    node->coeff = c;

    if(st == NULL){
        node->next = st;
        st = node;
    } else {
        temp = st;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        node->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = node;
    }
    printf(" %p", st);
}
```

and declare the the start pointer in the main method

```
N *strt = NULL;
node = malloc(sizeof *node);
insert(node, strt, 1, 1);
```

then run this four times like in the previous case, the values of start pointer gets changed 
after each call
`00560D18 00560D30 00560D48 00560D60`

Why does this happen?
And if i want to pass the start pointer as a parameter what changes should be made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

This happens because the change to `st` is invisible to the caller. That is `st = node` has **no effect whatsoever for the caller**. The function changes its own copy and after the function returns, if the caller prints `strt`, it will still be `NULL`.

This is a somewhat subtle consequence of the fact that in C arguments are passed by value, even pointers. So you pass `strt` by value. You can change `st->whatever` because it's a pointer and changes will propagate to the caller but changing `strt` itself will not work.

> And if i want to pass the start pointer as a parameter what changes
>   should be made

This is a regular question on this site and there is also a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) that describes the problem. A simple if somewhat cumbersome change that you can do is have the function take a 
`N **st` and pass `&strt`.

Comment: That's why while I was trying with normal integer values the values were changing, I should have checked the address as well. Thanks for the FAQ link.

Comment: what does this line mean " but changing strt itself will not work." ??

Comment: @shortCircuit It will not be reflected for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `strt` in your `main` method and `st` in the modified function `insert` are two different variables. The function call

```
insert(node, strt, 1, 1);
```

copies the value of `strt` which is defined in `main` to the function parameter `st` which is a different variable and is allocated on the stack when the function `insert` is invoked. Any changes made to `st` is visible inside the function only because it's a local variable. It goes out of scope once the function returns. Therefore, `strt` defined in `main` is still pointing to null and never gets changed. This means that the condition `st == NULL` is always true and the `if` block in `insert` is always executed and the local variable `st` is set to the newly created node each time the function `insert` is called. This would, in fact, cause memory leak because you lose the handle on the node once the function `insert` returns.

What you should do is to pass an address of the variable `strt` to `insert` so that the changes made to it is visible in `main`. Since you always append the new node at the end of the linked list, I suggest a few more changes.

```
void insert(N *node, N **st, int c, int e) {
    N *temp = *st;
    node->exponent = e;
    node->coeff = c;
    node->next = NULL;  // set it explicitly to NULL

    if(*st == NULL) {  // if head of the linked list is NULL
        *st = node;
    } 
    else {
        while(temp->next != NULL)  // reach the end of the linked list
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = node;   // add the new node at the end
    }
    printf("%p", *st);
}
```

And in `main`, invoke the function as

```
// in main method

N *strt = NULL;
node = malloc(sizeof *node);
insert(node, &strt, 1, 1);
```

Comment: 1  for demonstration with code. Both answers are complimentary. ^_^

Comment: why did you set the next explicitly to NULL

Comment: @shortCircuit for clarity.